# "trick" Exchange 2010 into allowing unauthenticated users to send mail to a group

Tags: exchange-2010

I would like to create a distribution list in Exchange 2010 that allows unauthenticated users to send mail to it.  I would like to add internal distribution lists that don't allow unauthenticated users to send email to them to this group.  Is there a way to get Exchange 2010 to allow mail to those groups within the group without having to allow unauthenticated users? In other words can I "trick" Exchange 2010 into allowing unauthenticated users to send to these groups by virtue of their inclusion in a group that allows unauthenticated users?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but here's an idea:

*Set up the address as a mailbox rather than a distribution group

*Set up an internal distribution group that contains all the other DG's that you want to send the mail to

*Configure the mailbox to forward all incoming mail to the distribution group.